# Absolute path of string that contains special characters

Tags: python

In my code, I get a path from the database that may contain special escaping characters that I need to convert them to a real path name. I'm using python 3.7 on Windows.
Suppose this path: `C:\Files\2c2b2541\00025\test.x`

**IMPORTANT**: the path is not a fixed value in the code and it is an output of executing a Stored Procedure from `pyodbc`.
When I try to convert it to an absolute path I get this error:

> ValueError: _getfullpathname: embedded null character in path

I also tried to replace `"\"` with `"/"` but with no luck.

```
import os

# path = cursor.execute(query, "some_input").fetchone()[0]
path = 'C:\Files\2c2b2541\00025\test.x'

print(os.path.abspath(path))
```

Comment: I have updated my answer and wrote a function that will give you the correct path. You can modify that based on your requirement. Please check and let me know in comment if it does not satisfy your requirement. Anyway, I learned a lot from your problem. Great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comments on the other answers, it sounds like the data is already corrupted in the database you're using. That is, you have a literal null byte stored there, and perhaps other bogus bytes (like `\2` perhaps turning into `\x02`). So you probably need two fixes.

First, you should fix whatever code is putting values into the database, so it won't put bogus data in any more. You haven't described how the data gets into the database, so I we can't give you much guidance on how to do this. But most programming languages (and DB libraries) have tools to prevent escape sequences from being evaluated in strings where they're not wanted.

Once you've stopped new bad data from getting added, you can work on fixing the values that are already in the database. It probably shouldn't be too hard to write a query that will replace `\0` null bytes with `\\0` (or whatever the appropriate escape sequence is for your DB). You may want to look for special characters like newlines (`\n`) and unprintable characters (like `\x02`) as well.

I'd only try to fix this issue on the output end if you don't have any control of the database at all.

Comment: Of course, it can be fixed on the database side, but I was wondering if python can handle this somehow. BTW, the output is a function on SQL server that returns path of an uploaded file in the database itself. So are you saying that python is **unable** to handle this?

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about your database specifically, but that sounds to me like there's a misconfiguration or bug in the library you use to access the database. There's no way it should be evaluating the escape sequences in a path it produces itself if its doing anything sane. You might want to ask a more specific question about your database code to get help with that, rather than trying to fix the output in Python. There are a lot of escape sequences it might be messing up, and since some of them *might* be valid in a path, it may be hard to tell which ones are errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below is the right way to solve your problem.

```
>>> def get_fixed_path(path):
...     path = repr(path)
...     path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\")
...     path = path.replace("\\x", "\\\\0")
...     path = os.path.abspath(path3).split("'")[1]
...     return path
...
>>>
>>> path = 'C:\Files\2c2b2541\00025\test.x'
>>> path
'C:\\Files\x02c2b2541\x0025\test.x'
>>>
>>> print(path)
C:\Filesc2b2541 25     est.x
>>>
>>> final_path = get_fixed_path(path)
>>> final_path
'C:\\Files\\002c2b2541\\00025\\test.x'
>>>
>>> print(final_path)
C:\Files\002c2b2541\00025\test.x
>>>
```

And here is the detailed description of each and every steps/statements in the above solution.

> First step (problem)

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> path = 'C:\Files\2c2b2541\00025\test.x'
>>> path
'C:\\Files\x02c2b2541\x0025\test.x'
>>>
>>> print(path)
C:\Filesc2b2541 25     est.x
>>>
```

> Second step (problem)

```
>>> path2 = repr(path)
>>> path2
"'C:\\\\Files\\x02c2b2541\\x0025\\test.x'"
>>>
>>> print(path2)
'C:\\Files\x02c2b2541\x0025\test.x'
>>>
```

> Third step (problem)

```
>>> path3 = path2.replace("\\", "\\\\")
>>> path3
"'C:\\\\\\\\Files\\\\x02c2b2541\\\\x0025\\\\test.x'"
>>>
>>> print(path3)
'C:\\\\Files\\x02c2b2541\\x0025\\test.x'
>>>
>>> path3 = path3.replace("\\x", "\\\\0")
>>> path3
"'C:\\\\\\\\Files\\\\\\002c2b2541\\\\\\00025\\\\test.x'"
>>>
>>> print(path3)
'C:\\\\Files\\\002c2b2541\\\00025\\test.x'
>>>
```

> Fourth step (problem)

```
>>> os.path.abspath(path3)
"C:\\Users\\RISHIKESH\\'C:\\Files\\002c2b2541\\00025\\test.x'"
>>>
>>> os.path.abspath(path2)
"C:\\Users\\RISHIKESH\\'C:\\Files\\x02c2b2541\\x0025\\test.x'"
>>>
>>> os.path.abspath('k')
'C:\\Users\\RISHIKESH\\k'
>>>
>>> os.path.abspath(path3).split("'")
['C:\\Users\\RISHIKESH\\', 'C:\\Files\\002c2b2541\\00025\\test.x', '']
>>> os.path.abspath(path3).split("'")[1]
'C:\\Files\\002c2b2541\\00025\\test.x'
>>>
```

> Final step (solution)

```
>>> final_path = os.path.abspath(path3).split("'")[1]
>>>
>>> final_path
'C:\\Files\\002c2b2541\\00025\\test.x'
>>>
>>> print(final_path)
C:\Files\002c2b2541\00025\test.x
>>>
```

Comment: downvoted because the OP said he got the string from a database; he isn't assigning the string himself.

Comment: @Dale, I respect your comment and appreciate down voting me to point my mistake. Now I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I like your method but you are replacing corrupted data based on the input, how about this path: `C:\Files\5c2b2541\00025\test.x` I get `C:\Files\005c2b2541\00025\test.x` on output.

Comment: Ok got, extra zeroes problem in `005c2b2541`. Let me solve and I'll let you here in comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\" by "\\".

That's it.

Comment: if you're using double quotes it needs to be: `s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\")`

Comment: Thanks for your remind, but I think he got my idea :D

Answer (score -1):

You need to either use a raw string literal or double backslashes `\\`.

```
import os
path = r'C:\Files\2c2b2541\00025\test.x' #r before the string

print(os.path.abspath(path))
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the path from the output of a database query so it is not a fixed value.